# How to get values of multiple Edit Text addview android and send it to MySQL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am building an android application where I am creating dynamic EdittextView. I need to send values of edittext to database. I have successfully send data to mysql in my parent layout, but not in my child layout. I mean, i cannot send data with double id in edittext.

Any solution?

BookingActivity.java

```
package com.anvilspc.anvilspc.kirindramayu;


import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.anvilspc.anvilspc.kirindramayu.helper.DatabaseHandler;
import com.anvilspc.anvilspc.kirindramayu.helper.SessionManager;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class BookingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String ServerURL = "url/api/test/booking.php";
    EditText nama_pemilik, tgl_booking, no_kendaraan;
    Button daftar_booking, buttonAdd;
    Spinner status_uji, jam_booking, jenis_kendaraan;
    String TempNokendaraan, TempNamapemilik, TempStatusuji, TempJeniskendaraan, TempJambooking, TempTglbooking, Tempemail;
    private int myear;
    private int mmonth;
    private int mday;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;
    private SessionManager session;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private LinearLayout container;
    List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    private HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking);
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();
        buttonBooking();
        buttonAdd();

    }


    public void buttonAdd() {


        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                        (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.field_booking,null);
                Button buttonRemove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                    }
                });

                container.addView(addView);
            }
        });
    }


    public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

        no_kendaraan = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.no_kendaraan);
        nama_pemilik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nama_pemilik);
        status_uji = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status_uji);
        jenis_kendaraan = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.jenis_kendaraan);
        tgl_booking = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tgl_booking);
        jam_booking = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.jam_booking);
        daftar_booking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.daftar_booking);


        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textview
        tgl_booking.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(mday).append("-").append(mmonth + 1).append("-")
                .append(myear).append(" "));
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {


        tgl_booking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                // set date picker as current date
                DatePickerDialog _date = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, myear, mmonth,
                        mday) {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        if (year < myear)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                        if (monthOfYear < mmonth && year == myear)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                        if (dayOfMonth < mday && year == myear && monthOfYear == mmonth)
                            view.updateDate(myear, mmonth, mday);

                    }
                };
                return _date;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            myear = selectedYear;
            mmonth = selectedMonth;
            mday = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into textview
            tgl_booking.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mday).append("-")
                    .append(mmonth + 1).append("-").append(myear)
                    .append(" "));

        }
    };

             public void buttonBooking() {

                 db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                 user = db.getUserDetails();
                 session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
                 daftar_booking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    GetData();

                    InsertData(TempNokendaraan, TempNamapemilik, TempStatusuji, TempJeniskendaraan, TempTglbooking, TempJambooking, Tempemail);

                }
            });
        }


        public void GetData()
        {


            TempNokendaraan = no_kendaraan.getText().toString();
            TempNamapemilik = nama_pemilik.getText().toString();
            TempStatusuji = status_uji.getSelectedItem().toString();
            TempJeniskendaraan = jenis_kendaraan.getSelectedItem().toString();
            TempTglbooking = tgl_booking.getText().toString();
            TempJambooking = jam_booking.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Tempemail = user.get("email");


        }

        public void InsertData(final String no_kendaraan, final String nama_pemilik, final String status_uji, final String jenis_kendaraan, final String tgl_booking,
                               final String jam_booking, final String email) {

            class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    String NokendaraanHolder = no_kendaraan;
                    String NamapemilikHolder = nama_pemilik;
                    String StatusujiHolder = status_uji;
                    String JeniskendaraanHolder = jenis_kendaraan;
                    String TglbookingHolder = tgl_booking;
                    String JambookingHolder = jam_booking;
                    String Emailholder = email;

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no_kendaraan", NokendaraanHolder));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama_pemilik", NamapemilikHolder));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status_uji", StatusujiHolder));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jenis_kendaraan", JeniskendaraanHolder));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tgl_booking", TglbookingHolder));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jam_booking", JambookingHolder));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Emailholder));


                    try {
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);

                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                    return "Jadwal Pengujian Berhasil di Daftarkan";
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    Toast.makeText(BookingActivity.this, "Jadwal Pengujian Berhasil di Daftarkan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();

                }
            }

            SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();

            sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(no_kendaraan, nama_pemilik, status_uji, jenis_kendaraan, tgl_booking, jam_booking, email);

        }
}
```

Booking.php

```
 <?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Jakarta");
    include 'connection.php' ;

     $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

     $no_kendaraan = $_POST['no_kendaraan'];
     $nama_pemilik = $_POST['nama_pemilik'];
     $status_uji = $_POST['status_uji'];
     $jenis_kendaraan = $_POST['jenis_kendaraan'];
     $tgl_booking = $_POST['tgl_booking'];
     $jam_booking = $_POST['jam_booking'];
     $tgl_mendaftar = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
     $email = $_POST['email'];


     $Sql_Query = "insert into tb_booking (no_kendaraan,nama_pemilik,status_uji, jenis_kendaraan, tgl_booking,jam_booking,tgl_mendaftar,email) values ('$no_kendaraan','$nama_pemilik', '$status_uji', '$jenis_kendaraan', '$tgl_booking', '$jam_booking', '$tgl_mendaftar', '$email')";


     if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){


     echo 'Data Submit Successfully';

     }
     else{

     echo 'Try Again';

     }
     mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "..i cannot send data with double id in edittext." . You have offered quite a bit of code. Please be more succinct and point out the code in question.